# Spring Setup and Installation

Tags: java, spring, installation

It is my first experience with Spring Framework. I am trying to perform the Installation and Setup from the following link: https://faun.pub/spring-framework-tutorial-89ec18b81246

1. I don't know if these are the correct steps to install Spring. If not, I ask you to suggest an alternative.
2. The link https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring that appears in the documentation does not exist (Not found) and all the websites suggest the same link to download the Spring version.

It is worth clarifying that I found the same documentation in Google on several pages (even check the official page of the framework) or Spring Boot information, which is not what I am currently looking for, I know they are different, with different purposes.

!Thank you!

I found this, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework, but it is the code of the Framework.

Comment: You can go through official docs of Spring --> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: Hi, but that is Spring Boot, not just Spring

Comment: This is Spring Doc. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: Thanks for the page, but i can't see how to install Spring with that page.

Comment: The tutorial you linked in your question is not an ideal starting point IMHO. Some things are explained inaccurately and the information (especially the installation/setup) is partially outdated. I strongly suggest that you start using a build tool like Maven or Gradle. The Spring framework is just another dependency you need to declare and then make use of it in your code. If you are a beginner, Spring Boot is an ideal place to start. Spring Boot is not *something different* but an extension which reduces (a lot of) boilerplate code and gets you started easily.

Answer (score 0):

refer to this link, Hope this will work for you.
https://youtu.be/Q6zUfJSsdP8